# HAML: Content into %input{:type => "Submit"} tag

Tags: html, forms, haml

Feels pretty lame.

This:

```
          %input{:type => "Submit"}
            %a.btn
              %i.icon-search.icon-white
```

generates this :

```
          <input type="Submit">
          <a class="btn">
            <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
          </a>
```

wheread this:

```
          %div{:type => "Submit"}
            %a.btn
              %i.icon-search.icon-white
```

generates this:

```
          <div type="Submit">
            <a class="btn">
              <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
```

How do I get:

```
          <input type="Submit">
            <a class="btn">
              <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
            </a>
          </input>
```

??

Thanks

Comment: buttons do not accept childs

Comment: You don't because that markup doesn't exist in (X)HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input type="Submit">
            <a class="btn">
              <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
            </a>
          </input>
```

this markup is not valid as per W3C

Input is single line tag which closes like this `<input type="button" />`
You can't put any of child element for Input tag
If you want to do same stuff with button tag then you can do

```
%button{type="button"}
  %a.btn
    %i.icon-search.icon-white
```

you will get

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  <a class="btn">
    <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
  </a>

</button>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but then I need some js to have the same button behaviour. Even if Bootstrap includes this behaviour by default, it feels like a hack instead of a clean solution.

Comment: You cant do it with Input element. You should use Button tag for same